# Multiple bootstrap tabs with DataTables. Child row only opening on one of the tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I have DataTables with child rows inside of 2 bootstrap tabs. The child rows do not consistently open inside the tab. They sometimes open on the first tab and sometimes on the second.

I want to create the container every time I click on the row and have it open. It sometimes opens in the second and sometimes in the first. It does not open in both tabs.

Here is my code:

```js
let json1 = [{
      "data": [
      {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Tiger Nixon",
          "position": "System Architect",
          "salary": "$320,800",
          "start_date": "2011/04/25",
          "office": "Edinburgh",
          "extn": "5421"
      },
      {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Garrett Winters",
          "position": "Accountant",
          "salary": "$170,750",
          "start_date": "2011/07/25",
          "office": "Tokyo",
          "extn": "8422"
      },
      {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Ashton Cox",
          "position": "Junior Technical Author",
          "salary": "$86,000",
          "start_date": "2009/01/12",
          "office": "San Francisco",
          "extn": "1562"
      },
      {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Cedric Kelly",
          "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
          "salary": "$433,060",
          "start_date": "2012/03/29",
          "office": "Edinburgh",
          "extn": "6224"
      },
      {
          "id": "5",
          "name": "Airi Satou",
          "position": "Accountant",
          "salary": "$162,700",
          "start_date": "2008/11/28",
          "office": "Tokyo",
          "extn": "5407"
      }
      ]
  }];
  let json2 = [{
      "data": [
      {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Harry Potter",
          "position": "System Architect",
          "salary": "$234,800",
          "start_date": "2013/04/25",
          "office": "Edinburgh",
          "extn": "5421"
      },
      {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Ron Weasley",
          "position": "Accountant",
          "salary": "$170,777",
          "start_date": "2011/09/25",
          "office": "Tokyo",
          "extn": "8422"
      },
      {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Herminone Granger",
          "position": "Junior Technical Author",
          "salary": "$175,000",
          "start_date": "2019/01/12",
          "office": "San Francisco",
          "extn": "1562"
      },
      {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Neville Logbottom",
          "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
          "salary": "$555,060",
          "start_date": "2015/03/29",
          "office": "Edinburgh",
          "extn": "6224"
      },
      {
          "id": "5",
          "name": "Luna Lovegood",
          "position": "Accountant",
          "salary": "$200,700",
          "start_date": "2017/11/28",
          "office": "Tokyo",
          "extn": "5407"
      }
      ]
  }];
  var table;
  const create_datatable =(js, tab) => {
    js.forEach(d => {
        table = $(`#${tab}`).DataTable( {
            "bDestroy": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "data": d.data,
            columns: [{
                className: 'details-control',
                orderable: false,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
            }, {
                data: 'name', className:'names'
            }, {
                data: 'position', className:'position'
            }, {
                data: 'office', className:'office'
            }, {
                data: 'salary', className:'salary'
            }]
        } );
    });
}
create_datatable(json1, 'example');
create_datatable(json2, 'example2');

const create_cont = (tab) => {
    var containers = document.createElement('div');
    containers.setAttribute("id", `${tab}_scatter`);
    $(`#${tab} tbody`).on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
      }
      else {
        if ( table.row( '.shown' ).length ) $('.details-control', table.row( '.shown' ).node()).click();
        $(`#${tab}_scatter`).html('test');
        row.child(containers).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
}
create_cont('example');
create_cont('example2');
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Show Child Row</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Tab 2</h3>
  <table id="example2" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Show Child Row</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I fix it so that the row opens with my text('test') whenever I click the left-most column, a child row always happens?

I am creating a container every time I click on the row because I want to eventually add dynamic charts inside child row.

Comment: What is the issue? The description of the problem, and your goal is not clear. The code seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If you click on the left-most value the child row does not open consistently. If it opens in the first tab it does not open in the second and if it opens in the second it does not open in the first.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why aren't the child rows opening in both tabs?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you set `table` within the loop. Therefore it will only ever contain a reference to the *last* DataTable which was created.

To fix this, get the DataTable reference from the `table` element within the click handler:

```js
let json1 = [{data:[{id:"1",name:"Tiger Nixon",position:"System Architect",salary:"$320,800",start_date:"2011/04/25",office:"Edinburgh",extn:"5421"},{id:"2",name:"Garrett Winters",position:"Accountant",salary:"$170,750",start_date:"2011/07/25",office:"Tokyo",extn:"8422"},{id:"3",name:"Ashton Cox",position:"Junior Technical Author",salary:"$86,000",start_date:"2009/01/12",office:"San Francisco",extn:"1562"},{id:"4",name:"Cedric Kelly",position:"Senior Javascript Developer",salary:"$433,060",start_date:"2012/03/29",office:"Edinburgh",extn:"6224"},{id:"5",name:"Airi Satou",position:"Accountant",salary:"$162,700",start_date:"2008/11/28",office:"Tokyo",extn:"5407"}]}];
let json2 = [{data:[{id:"1",name:"Harry Potter",position:"System Architect",salary:"$234,800",start_date:"2013/04/25",office:"Edinburgh",extn:"5421"},{id:"2",name:"Ron Weasley",position:"Accountant",salary:"$170,777",start_date:"2011/09/25",office:"Tokyo",extn:"8422"},{id:"3",name:"Herminone Granger",position:"Junior Technical Author",salary:"$175,000",start_date:"2019/01/12",office:"San Francisco",extn:"1562"},{id:"4",name:"Neville Logbottom",position:"Senior Javascript Developer",salary:"$555,060",start_date:"2015/03/29",office:"Edinburgh",extn:"6224"},{id:"5",name:"Luna Lovegood",position:"Accountant",salary:"$200,700",start_date:"2017/11/28",office:"Tokyo",extn:"5407"}]}];

const create_datatable = (js, tab) => {
  js.forEach(d => {
    $(`#${tab}`).DataTable({
      "bDestroy": true,
      "responsive": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "data": d.data,
      columns: [{
        className: 'details-control',
        orderable: false,
        data: null,
        defaultContent: '',
      }, {
        data: 'name',
        className: 'names'
      }, {
        data: 'position',
        className: 'position'
      }, {
        data: 'office',
        className: 'office'
      }, {
        data: 'salary',
        className: 'salary'
      }]
    });
  });
}
create_datatable(json1, 'example');
create_datatable(json2, 'example2');

const create_cont = (tab) => {
  var containers = document.createElement('div');
  containers.setAttribute("id", `${tab}_scatter`);
  
  $(`#${tab} tbody`).on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {  
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    let table = tr.closest('table').DataTable(); // retrieve Datatable reference here
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      if (table.row('.shown').length) $('.details-control', table.row('.shown').node()).click();
      $(`#${tab}_scatter`).html('test');
      row.child(containers).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
}
create_cont('example');
create_cont('example2');
```

```css
td.details-control {
  background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
  background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Show Child Row</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <table id="example2" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Show Child Row</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```